# Can I run Ruby (1.9.1) in a mode that writes what commands are being called?

Tags: ruby, debugging

I'm trying to understand a medium-size library and I would like to run a test script so that I would see the commands that are being processed.

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: What you want is a debugger, which is a tool to trace the flow of execution in a piece of software.

Comment: Yeah but something like this for Ruby: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/debugging-shell-script.html would suffice me.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend learning how to use the debugger. It makes it so easy to learn what code is doing, whether it's behaving or misbehaving.

Comment: @theTinMan: And what debugger do you recommend for Ruby on Windows? I'm kind of new to Ruby. And as I have PHP background I'm sceptical to debuggers for scripting languages.

Comment: PHP I'm not familiar with enough to comment on any debuggers, but Perl, Python and Ruby have excellent debuggers available to them, and are all scripting languages. Personally, I use "debugger" for Ruby on Linux and Mac OS. I don't use Windows so I don't know if it runs there, but I assume it will if you got Ruby installed.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Kernel#set_trace_func](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-set_trace_func) to trace all `call` events:

```
class Foo
  def bar
  end
end

set_trace_func proc { |event, file, line, id, binding, classname|
  if event == "call"
    printf "%8s %s:%-2d %10s %8s\n", event, file, line, id, classname
  end
}

Foo.new.bar

# =>    call foo.rb:2         bar      Foo
```